# ORM auto-creation of tables violates DBA preferences

Tags: database, oop, language-agnostic, orm

I am using ORM to automatically create tables from model classes.  I am naming the classes and their fields in a way that is natural for the application.  The ORM then uses those same names for the tables and columns, and automatically generates names of other objects like constraints and sequences which are completely abstracted by the ORM.

I am not declaring how the tables, columns, etc. should be named.  I leave it to the ORM to decide.  I see this as good sense from the application's point of view.

The DBA for my team does not like this one bit.  The DBA says that if column "B" in table "A" has a foreign key constraint to field "Y" in table "X", that the name **must** be "A.X_Y" instead of "A.B".  The DBA says this is the "correct" way to name foreign keys and that the ORM is therefore naming them *incorrectly*.  Both of the ORM engines I am familiar with allow class/field names to be explicitly mapped to table/column names, so I am aware it is possible to accommodate the DBA without changing the classes.

**My question is**, in practice, does doing this (explicitly mapping the names) necessarily introduce an extra entity(i.e. new configuration files/sections, new code) or coupling (i.e. imports, decorators, annotations) in the application that might not otherwise exist?  ORM designs vary, so I would think it is possible that the answer is different for different engines.

If the answer to this is nearly universally yes, I would consider that a good argument that the DBA should yield to the ORM in the interest of productivity, on the logic that the database exists to serve the needs of the application, not the other way around.  Commentary on this point is welcome also.

Please note, I am NOT asking for specific recommendations on how classes/fields/tables/columns should be named.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone - I'm sorry, I edited your comment by mistake instead of replying to it, and now I can't revert.  For Django I think you are correct.  I guess I am really asking about ORMs in which your classes will not necessarily be mapped to tables (in Django model classes are always for the purpose of mapping to tables).

Comment: I deleted my comment when I realized your question covered it already. oops. ^_^;

Comment: BTW, it is generally not a good strategy to get into fights with the DBA. Standards like these are like coding standards for us programmers: they're there to make it easier to bring other developers onboard, and to make bugs more obvious.

Comment: Were I your manager, I'd say that you were increasing risk because, should you be unavailable, your code would be harder for another developer to fix.  Another way to look at it: if you're the only one that can maintain your code, sure it's job security, but you will also never be free of maintaining that code, since maintenance couldn't be easily transferred to a junior developer. Also, if you have found a better way to write something in code, and you keep it from the team so it doesn't get incorporated into the standard, well, that's just mean.

Comment: @Mike: My philosophy has been that good developers write maintainable code, even if variable names etc. don't always have the same format.  Development blogs and literature, and many open source projects, support this thinking at least somewhat.  Of course, this thinking simply does not fly in many large companies.  People always give me positive feedback on code quality and readability/maintainability (except in cases where they do not know the language/API being used).  But you make a good case to fall in line.  Thanks for your comments. +1 for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORM designs vary, so I would think it is possible that the answer is different for different engines.

You are right here. Depending on the ORM, explicitly specifying the field->column mapping might (or might not) introduce extra entities in the form of configuration entries, annotations, attributes etc. Having said that, this is the bread and butter (or should I say the very basics) for an ORM engine and hence handling these mappings usually does not add a noticeable overhead.

I feel you definitely cannot use this as an argument against explicitly naming the tables,columns etc. Most often than not you would have another application that would use the same database. The default names generated by your application might make absolutely no sense for that application. I would let the DBA decide the right nomenclature for the database artifacts and tweak the mapping to my domain model, in my app. After all that's where the ORM adds value.

Comment: Thanks.  This answer really helped me resolve the basic conflict in my mind, by pointing out that these issues really are part of what ORM "is for", and not simply a necessary-evil kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, explicitly mapping the names does not create an extra entity or coupling; it defines a policy and process which your DBA has decided to be appropriate for their database(s).  I'd contend, as well, that your logic is a bit backwards; the application exists to serve the needs of the database.  The software which ANY company puts in place exists to serve / populate / present the data which exists in the database, not the other way around.

Consider this; the software that does whatever your company does will change as requirements and technology change, and get refactored as standards and complexity evolve.  The data which is stored in the database, however, will not; even as the schema changes / evolves, the data underlying will change very little, if at all.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example in which accommodating the policy is a change, and not entirely new configuration/code?

Comment: Also I'm very surprised by your assertion that the application serves the needs of the database.  While we may assume that stackoverflow.com relies on one or more databases, we users don't really care about the database, we care about stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @wberry: I don't quite understand your question about "accomodating the policy is a change".  Also, I would contend very strongly that the users on stackoverflow don't care (particularly much) about the software that runs the site; but we care about the questions (i.e., the data which is stored in the database).

Comment: No, we care about the *data in* the database, and there's a lot more of it than code. StackOverflow can go crazy changing the UI, but if my questions/answers/comments get corrupted, I'm ditching it. As for a concrete example, in Django, to use the DBA's names I just have to add a `db_column=` parameter to each field and a `db_table` property to the model's `Meta` class. Easy as pie. There are also `db_index` and `db_tablespace` parameters if I need them.

Comment: Fascinating.  I perceive an almost fundamental difference in interpretation of the concept of an "application".

Comment: Let me explain from a different angle. If your application pulls in a library, do you demand that the library's naming conventions match yours?  Okay, maybe you do, and you could get away with it if it's an internal library and you have the authority, but most of the time, it's not gonna happen. Why? Because there are other applications that use that library that will break if the names change.  The good of the many > the good of the few, and all that. Same goes for databases: there are usually multiple applications per DB, and so a DB change causes a lot more pain than an app change.

Comment: @wberry:  Process is not an end in and of itself; good process can make data accessible, and bad process can hinder the use of data, but in the end, it's about the data.  What is Stack Overflow without the questions and answers?  Nothing.  What is Amazon without the products they sell?  Nothing.  Google without search results?  Nothing.  Facebook without user posts?  Nothing.  On the application side, what is Word without savefiles?  Nothing.  Without persistent data, you can make an application of the approximate complexity level of the desktop calculator, but not much more.

Answer (score 1):

Coding standards exist for a reason - if I were the DBA, I might suggest that the productivity benefit of using the ORM without modification should yield in the name of maintainability.

It's a question of trade-offs: if the additional effort to name the foreign key column according to the corporate standard is minimal (and in most ORMs I've worked with, it is), I'd just do it.

If your ORM makes it super hard, I'd explain to the DBA that this is a different architecture than the one he's used to - the use of an ORM means there will rarely if ever be any manual SQL writing - it's all automagically created by the ORM, so it makes sense to relax the coding standards.

Comment: Actually, if the ORM makes it super hard, then that's a good reason to find a different ORM.  Keeping that ORM means everyone who uses the DB needs to use that ORM, and by necessity the language it's written in, which means every other application has to change to adopt the ORM.

Comment: This is valid I think.  I had in mind the scenario where the application is known to be the only user of the tables, for example where the tables are used for app configuration.  For transactional tables with other applications using them, there's no question that the DBA wins.